# PERL - renaming a file member in zip64 archive

Tags: perl, zip, compression

I am changing a PERL code that does compression to be able to handle the `zip64` extension.

the old code is using `Archive::Zip` module that can be used as follows.

```
# Create a Zip file
use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS );
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();

# Add a file from disk
my $file_member = $zip->addFile( 'xyz.pl', 'AnotherName.pl' );
```

`Archive::Zip` doesn't support `zip64` extension and because of that I am using `IO::Compress::Zip` module instead.

I am looking for a way to mimic the `addfFile` functionality some way or another, renaming while zipping or maybe editing the archives after zipping.

I can't find any PERL module that can help me in doing so.

1. Is there any way in PERL to do that ?
2. In case there is not a direct way, can I change something in the
   header of the archive file to rename its members ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is the same question you asked over on PerlMonks [Renaming a file member in zip64 archive](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=1096467)?

If so, here is the same reply.

Try this - it will automatically create the output file as a Zip64 compliant Zip archive if required (i.e. if the size exceed 4 Gig or you have > 64k members in the zip archive). Otherwise it creates a standard Zip archive.

```
use Archive::Zip::SimpleZip qw($SimpleZipError) ;

my $z = new Archive::Zip::SimpleZip "my1.zip"
    or die "Cannot create zip file: $SimpleZipError\n" ;

$z->add('xyz.pl', Name => 'AnotherName.pl' );


$z->close();
```

If you want to force the creation of a Zip64 archive (even when the archive is small enough not to need it) add the **Zip64** option when creating the Archive::Zip::SimpleZip object, like this

```
my $z = new Archive::Zip::SimpleZip "my1.zip", Zip64 => 1
    or die "Cannot create zip file: $SimpleZipError\n" ;
```

Comment: Thank you,  but I am trying not to add one more dependency to the project.

Comment: It is possible to achieve exactly the same thing with IO::Compress::Zip (Archive::Zip::SimpleZip is just a small wrapper around it), but with more code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a way to do it with IO::Compress::Zip, but.
Why do not you rename files before adding them to archive?
If you need to preserve original files with its names, copy the files to some temp folder, rename, and to archive and delete from temp after.